# ActionScript 3 event forwarding illegal?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

If I do this

```
stuff.addEventListener(FooEvent.NAME, function(e:FooEvent) {
   dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

I get a runtime error saying that Event cannot be converted to FooEvent.
However, it works fine if I do:

```
stuff.addEventListener(FooEvent.NAME, function(e:FooEvent) {
   dispatchEvent(new FooEvent(e.things));
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dispatchEvent calls `clone` on the passed event, if that event is already "used" (i.e. has been dispatched). from what you say, I am quite sure you did not override `FooEvent`'s `clone`-method and thus it uses `Event`'s implementation which returns a plain vanilla `Event`. That's the source of your error.

You need to override the `clone` method in `FooEvent` in order to return appropriate instances of `FooEvent`.